# mvc3 entity object with extra field not saved

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I am writing an mvc3 application with Entity. I am brand new to .net and entity, so this question may be basic.

I have a model in that represents an object that gets saved to the database. But I would like to have an extra field display on the create and edit forms that is not saved to the database.

Is there a way to specify that a field is not saved with the rest of the object? Also, is there a way to make a field required on create and not on edit?

I would just hard code it, but I would like to include it in the validation that can be set on the entity models.

I am using Entity code first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use viewmodels for displaying or editing, while saving map your view model to domain model(excluding the non-desired fields) and then save it. You can use a tool `auto mapper` to map your view models to domain models.

say for example you have a domain class person

```
public class Person
{
public string Name {get; set;}
public string Address {get; set;}
}
```

then you make a view model

```
public class VMPerson
{
public string Name {get; set;}
public string Address {get; set;}
public int Age{get;set;}
}
```

fetch data into your view model and pass it to your view the query may look like

```
var q = (from p in db.Person 
        select new VMPerson{
         Name = p.name,
         Address = p.address,
         Age = 16
         }).SingleOrDefault();

return q;
```

in your view the age will also be displayed, then on post

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Person(VMPerson vmperson)
{
Person p = new Person()// your domain object
// mapping part here
p.name =  vmperson.name;
p.address = vmperson;

TryUpdateModel(p);
db.Person.Save();
}
```

Comment: Do you know of any examples of doing this that I can look at?